# When I add a Fragment to my project, I get: Failed to resolve: support-v4 Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

When I add a Fragment to my project, I get: Failed to resolve: support-v4 Error

[This is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGT84.jpg)

[Screen shot of app gradle.build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGCvQ.jpg)

Comment: share app build.gradle

Comment: edited it on the post

Comment: replace com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 with com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1

Comment: according to this page [Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

Comment: Thanks I replaced those and it worked!! but I don't get it, what was wrong with it?

Comment: lowered my API to 26 and it work perfectly now.